# Show/hide validation message wrapped inside bootstrap's <span class="help block"> in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Developed an reusable directive say CustomerCheckDirective which validates whether the details typed in input is valid or not as below.

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[customerCheck]'
})

export class CustomerCheckDirective implements OnChanges {
    @Output()
    isValidCustomer: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
    ....
    // method validates and emits based on some logic
    {
        this.isValidCustomer.emit(false); // can be true or false
    }
}
```

Have developed simple component page with template consuming the above directive.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'validate-customers-demo',
    template: `
    <validate-page [componentSelector]="'customerCheck'">        
        <div>            
            <div class="row">   
                <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error': isValidCustomer }">
                    <label>Enter customer details</label>
                    <input class="form-control" customerCheck (isValidCustomer)="setIsValidCustomer($event)" >
                    <span class="help-block" [hidden]="isValidCustomer"> Not a valid customer </span>                    
                </div>
            </div>
            ...
    </validate-page> 
`
})

export class CustomerCheckComponent {    
    isValidCustomer: boolean;
    .....
    setIsValidCustomer(isValidCustomer: boolean): void {
        this.isValidCustomer = isValidCustomer;
    }
....
}
```

But in UI on the page load it below/beside input text field it always show message "Not a valid customer" even on page load. Based on boolean emit of directive the  validation message wrapped inside bootstrap's  should be shown or hide?.

Note: Initial my approach was use of  and it worked.

```
<i [hidden]="isValidCustomer" style="size:15px;">Not a valid customer</i>
```

Any help on this?.

Comment: can you post the validation logic inside the directive?

Comment: @Karim, could not post because of business critical. But the validation inside returns you either true or false value from the directive.